# Sitecore SPEAK - Unable to add new item

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.5, sitecore-speak-ui

I am using Sitecore 7.5 initial version and trying to add a new item in Sitecore SPEAK. There is no SPEAK option in the left, all I have is `Recent`, `Non-system` , `System` and `All`. I'm unable to add a item of any type as it always appears to have the `Loading...` message.
Am I missing something here?

I included a screenShot of what I am currently getting

[image: Sitecore SPEAK]

Answer (score 1):

You have a search in the top of the screen for homepage. If you clear this do the SPEAK components load correctly? This is a filter for the components.

I think Sitecore ROCKS loads the last searxh, it's caught me out a few times :).

Glad it appears my suggestion below to upgrade to SPEAK 1.4 helped :)

Comment: Even after clearing the search filter the components are not loading. I believe you need to select SPEAK on the left side to add an item like tree list. But that is missing in my instance.

Comment: What version of sitecore is your solution on, and are you using the latest sitecore rocks?

Comment: The other question is when you load a web browser, go to your local website/ sitecore and log in, does it work or error?

Comment: I am using site core 7.5 and site core ROCKS 1.3.5. Yes the website/sitecore works fine and i am able to work in the content editor. The only issue is that I am unable to add a new item in the YourApps folder of /Sitecore/client.

Comment: Are you able to add any other items or is it just speak componts that don't load. There is a sitecore rocks 1.4 you could try upgrading too and see if that works.

Comment: Upgrading to 1.4 helped . Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I had a separate issue with the TDS and my project was unable to connect to site core. I had to do a fresh start and get all the code again and do a solution setup. Now the TDS issue is resolved and the SPEAK is not working again :( . I'm clueless on whats going on. I am still using site core rocks 1.4 . The website /sitecore opens and i am able to log in. All the site core related features work except the SPEAK. I am not able to add a new item. Any help is appreciated.